# Scala Exception Handling - Advice Needed

Tags: scala

I have the following piece of code that makes a request to a HTTP service to fetch a resource. It could be that the service is not available or the resource is not available. So I need to handle such error scenarios. The server actually throws an exception that I have to handle in my Scala client. Here is what I have done so far:

```
  def getData(resource: String, requestParam: Option[Seq[(String, String)]]): Try[Elem] = {
    Try {
      val wc = WebClient.create(address(scheme, host, port) + "/" + resource, un, pw, null)

      // Load the trust store to the HTTPConduit
      if ("https" == scheme) {
        val conduit = WebClient.getConfig(wc).getConduit.asInstanceOf[HTTPConduit]
        loadTrustStore(conduit)
      }

      requestParam match {
        case Some(reqParams) => reqParams.foreach((param: (String, String)) => {
          wc.query(param._1, param._2)
        })
        case None => wc
      }
      XML.loadString("""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>""" + wc.get(classOf[String]))
    }
  }
```

Now, the caller of this method looks like this:

```
def prepareDomainObject(): MyDomainObject = {
  getData(resource, params) match {
  case Success(elem) => getDomainFromElem(elem)
  case Failure(_) => ?? What do I do here? I actually want to get the message in the Throwable and return another type. How do I get around this?
}
```

How do I handle my match condition such that I return a different type in case of an error?

Comment: Are you just trying to figure out how to work with the `Throwable` that the `Failure` is wrapping in that match statement?  If so I can provide some solutions in an answer.

Comment: And also, given a `Failure`, what kind of `MyDomainObject` would you then want to return?

Comment: When there is a failure, it does not make sense to return any domain object at all. I want to take a different route, but at the same time I do not want to change the method signature of the prepareDomainObject method.

Comment: Your needs sort of seem to contradict each other.  It sounds like callers of `prepareDomainObject` need to differentiate between successes and failures (maybe by changing the result to a `Try[MyDomainObject]`) but you are saying that you don't want to change the return type.  I don't see a great clean (non hack) way to return a `MyDomainObject` that could be interpreted as a failure without changing the return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options. Either have `prepareDomainObject` return a `Try` as well:

```
def prepareDomainObject(): Try[MyDomainObject] = {
  getData(resource, params) map getDomainFromElem
}
```

or have it throw an exception on error:

```
def prepareDomainObject(): MyDomainObject = {
  getDomainFromElem(getData(resource, params).get)
}
```